# MOSFET N-CHANNEL don't switch

Tags: mosfet, switching-regulator, batteries, low-battery

I am controlling the voltage of a 3.6V lithium battery with a [MCP112-250](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001889F.pdf) (I know it is 3V but I have a diode in series with my battery).
And the output is connected to the gate of a N-channel MOSFET, [IRFB7430PbF](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfb7430pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015356169bcd1e53) according to this schematic :
[image]
The MCP112 is doing his job by toggling his ouptup from high to low. 

When Vin>2.5V I have my MCP112 output high and I have 2.5V at Vout of the LDO, and when Vin<2.5V I have my MCP112 low but I don't have 0V as expected but aproximately 1.2V when Vin=2.2V. 
My circuit is not shut down as expected... Theoretically when I have a 0V on the gate of a N-channel it has to be "open" so my system is off.

But why is this working like there were no MOSFET ?

**EDIT:**

It seems I have some current leaking from somewhere... Because when the MOSFET is removed I have Vout=~2V ...But from where ? I used a GND power plane on my board. Is it possible that current is leaking between the pads and the power plane ?

Comment: First of all your FET has a max threshold voltage of 3.9V, so you may never get it fully enhanced.  What's the load on your output?  You will have some leakage through the FET so it's conceivable that you would see some voltage on the output if there was no load.  Or you may have damaged the FET with ESD or in some other way and the gate oxide has been punched through.  Try putting a 1K load on the output and see what happens.

Comment: It was with no load, but with a 12kOhm load (I juste have this one on my hand) I have the same problem. Vin=2.4V and Vout=1.5V instead of 0V..

Comment: You have the FET in backwards (drain and source swapped) or you have a bad FET,  or other wiring error.

Comment: @JohnD It's soldered on a board with silkscreen so it can't be backward and my package is good... I am going to change it to see what happens. I let you know !

Comment: OK, good luck, though it wouldn't be the first time that a PCB and silkscreen got the drain and source connections backwards.  Has this board been proven and it's only this one that's having the problem?  If so, a bad FET is the most likely explanation.

Comment: I changed it and I have the same problem... I quadruple checked if the source and drain where backward and it's not.. And it is the only MOSFET on my board.

Comment: Does the MCP112's output go down to 0V with the FET disconnected? The MCP1700 is rated for 0.25A max. Why are you using a FET rated for 195A? An IRLML2502 would be more than adequate - and is specified for 2.5V Gate drive.

Comment: If the MCP112's output go down with the FET why without it will not? Besides I used this one http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/652230.pdf for the second test because I only had one of the IRFB7430. And I need the FET to be through hole...

Comment: If you completely remove the FET does the output go to zero?  How about if you hard short (jumper) gate to source?

Comment: Try a Pull down drain resistor at the gate.

Comment: I tried with the Pull-down resistor on the Gate : same problem. I will try without the MOSFET, but I don't really get the point... Because If I remove the mosfet, I have no use of the MCP112, and so I don't have any protection... I am missing something ?

Comment: Here is what I think the circuit is supposed to do. When Vin > 2.5V, U1 will be connected to Vin, and will power up. When Vin < 2.5V, Q1 is supposed to turn off and disconnect U1 from Vin. Is that what you think is supposed to happen? If so, please verify that when Q1 is removed, U1 has no voltage applied from VIN (pin 2) to VSS (pin 1). The thought is that maybe there is some alternate path to GND. Maybe Q1 IS off, but there is current leaking around it somehow. If you remove Q1, and still see Voltage applied to U1, then you know the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @mkeith Ok I understand ! I try and I let you know.

Comment: @mkeith Ok this is strange ! You are right... When I remove the mosfet the MCP112 is doing his job, but I have Vout = ~2V .... It should be 0V because the circuit is open !

Comment: Are you measuring your output using the 2 pins of your J1 or J2, of have you connected one end of your multimeter to the battery negative?

Comment: @brhans When measuring from the battery negative and Vout of the LDO I have 2.3V for Vin=3.3V. But measuring from the pins of J1 or J2 I have 0V... I think I now what you are going to say... To replace the MOSFET and measured from the 2 pins of my connectors right? .. And If I have 0V when Vin<2.5V my circuit is working correctly .. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @brhans I am a F****N' NOOB !! My circuit was working from the beginning of the universe !! The problem was just that I was taking the wrong ground... You really saved my night ! Thank you ! <3 And thank you all for your help !

Comment: That's what I suspected ... the part about wrong ground - not you being a noob ofc ...

Comment: Tagadac, write up a brief answer to your own question, and accept it. That is allowed. And it may help people in the future.

Comment: Also, I specifically asked you to measure from Vin to VSS on U1 to make sure you got the right "ground." FYI. ;-)

Comment: @mkeith Yes but in my head VSS (pin 1) was the ground, so it was the negative pole of the battery...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**
 If you are "cutting" the ground make sure you are measuring your output from where you realy want to measure it !
In my case I was measuring Vout from Vout of the LDO and the negative pole of the battery, so when Vin>2.5V Vout=2.5V, but when Vin<2.5V the MOSFET disconnect the ground of the battery from the rest of the circuit so between Vout and the negative pole of the battery there is a remaining voltage. But if you are measuring between the 2 pins of J1 or J2 you should see 0V, but if you are measuring from Vout on J1 or J2 and the negative pole of the battery you are not measuring what you are expecting... So this is why I got strange voltage on my multi-meter...
**In short:**
When you are measuring a voltage with your multi-meter make sure to measure with **the good ground reference** !